# How to bridge two faces (loop edges) which have diffrent number of vertex

Tags: modeling

I want to make a cone with round bottom and rectangle top, how can i bridge them to get symmertic?
[image]

Comment: That video solved my question!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zc8fFp5gr0A

Answer (score 1):

[image]I suggest different approach.

add plane, shape it , subdivide than extrude with z presed
than with just top loop selected (extruded edge)
go->mesh->transfor>to sphere

remember! extrude edge not whole plane!

Comment: Hi, it seems it doenst work with non-square rectangular http://i111.fastpic.ru/big/2020/0505/d3/5913ddcacf13d8b90496e5da194a4dd3.png